# How to apply this function to an array without reusing all elements

Tags: javascript, html

I'm fairly new to programming and I'm working on a project,

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="textAnimation">
        <span><h2 class="animatedHeader">Text1</h2></span>
        <span
          ><h2 class="animatedHeader twoH">Text2</h2></span
        >
        <span
          ><h2 class="animatedHeader">Text3</h2></span
        >
        <span
          ><h2 class="animatedHeader">text4</h2></span
        >
        <span><h2 class="animatedHeader">text5</h2></span>
        <span><h2 class="animatedHeader">text6</h2></span>
        <span><h2 class="animatedHeader">text7</h2></span>
        <span><h2 class="animatedHeader">text8</h2></span>
        <span><h2 class="animatedHeader">text9</h2></span>
</div>
```

---

**JavaScript**

```
// Check if is in viewport & animate
      const headers2 = document.querySelector(".twoH");
      function elementInViewportTWO() {
        let bounding = headers2.getBoundingClientRect();

        if (
          bounding.top >= 0 &&
          bounding.left >= 0 &&
          bounding.right <=
            (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
          bounding.bottom <=
            (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
        ) {
          headers2.style.opacity = 1;
        } else {
          headers2.style.opacity = 0.6;
        }
      }
      setInterval(elementInViewportTWO, 10);
```

---

My questions is, how to apply this effect, given an array of 9 headings without reusing so much code, how do I make my function work with an array of elements?
(My code highlights text when a certain element is in a viewport)

Comment: Just because nobody pointed it out: It's invalid HTML to put a block element (`h2`) inside a `span`. It probably works because the browser is fixing the error, but it would be better to change it and use, for example, a `div` instead of. the `span`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select them all with `document.querySelectorAll` and loop through them each time.

```js
// Check if is in viewport & animate
      const headers = document.querySelectorAll(".animatedHeader");
      function elementsInViewport() {
        headers.forEach(header=>{
        let bounding = header.getBoundingClientRect();

        if (
          bounding.top >= 0 &&
          bounding.left >= 0 &&
          bounding.right <=
            (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) &&
          bounding.bottom <=
            (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight)
        ) {
          header.style.opacity = 1;
        } else {
          header.style.opacity = 0.6;
        }
        })
      }
      setInterval(elementsInViewport, 10);
```

```html
<div class="textAnimation">
        <span><h2 class="animatedHeader">Text1</h2></span>
        <span
          ><h2 class="animatedHeader twoH">Text2</h2></span
        >
        <span
          ><h2 class="animatedHeader">Text3</h2></span
        >
        <span
          ><h2 class="animatedHeader">text4</h2></span
        >
        <span><h2 class="animatedHeader">text5</h2></span>
        <span><h2 class="animatedHeader">text6</h2></span>
        <span><h2 class="animatedHeader">text7</h2></span>
        <span><h2 class="animatedHeader">text8</h2></span>
        <span><h2 class="animatedHeader">text9</h2></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The function you've provided evaluates the dimensions of each `.animatedHeader` element every 10 milliseconds. This will make your CPU work very hard and has a high chance of hurting your site's peformance. And because of `setInterval` it will keep on running even if you're not interacting with the site and nothing changes.

Instead, consider using the [Intersection Observer API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) which is specifically designed to detect if elements are within a viewport whilst keeping the performance high.

```
const headers = document.querySelectorAll('.animatedHeader');

const intersectionCallback = entries => {
  for (const { isIntersecting, target } of entries) {
    if (isIntersecting) {
      target.style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
      target.style.opacity = 0.6;
    }
  }
};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(intersectionCallback);

for (const header of headers) {
  observer.observe(header);
}
```